# What kind of algorithm does this recurrence relation represent?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Take a look at this recurrence relation for algorithm complexity:

```
T(n) = 2 T(n-1) - 1
```

What kind of algorithm does this recurrence relation represent. Notice that there's a `minus` instead of `plus`, so it can't be a divide and conquer algorithm.

What kind of algorithm will have complexity with this as it's recurrence relation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Your question may be on topic on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ (but check their rules and expectations before posting).

Answer (score 1):

```
T(n) =  2 T(n-1)-1
T(n) =  4 T(n-2)-3
T(n) =  8 T(n-3)-7
T(n) = 16 T(n-4)-15
...
T(n) = 2^k T(n-k) - 2^(k-1)
```

If, for example `T(1) = O(1)` then

```
T(n) = 2^(n-1) O(1) - 2^(n-2) = O(2^(n-1)) = O(2^n)
```

which is an exponential growth.

---

Now let's see that `O(1) - 1 = O(1)`. From CLRS:

> `O(g(n))` = { `f(n)` : there exist positive constants `c` and `n0` such that `0 <= f(n) <= c g(n)` for all `n >= n0` }

Thus to remove effect of `-1` we just need to increase hidden constant `c` by one.

So, as long as your base case have complexity like `O(1)`, `O(n)` with `n > 0` you shouldn't care about `-1`. In other words if you base case makes recurrence `T(n) = 2 T(n-1)` at least exponential in `n` you don't care about this `-1`.

---

Example: imagine that you are asked to told if a string `S` with `n` characters contains specified character. And you proceed like this, you run algorithm recursively on `S[0..n-2]` and `S[1..n-1]`. You stop the recursion when string is one character length, then you just check the character.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the time complexity given, it is an exponential algorithm.

For reduction of size by 1, you are multiplying the time by 2 (approximately)

So it does not come under any polynomial time algorithmic paradigms like divide and conquer, dynamic programming, ...

Comment: So you've basically stated things that OP has already said.